# php обрезать дату со строки. Упростить регулярное выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно обрезать дату со строки:

```
team of moderators for inspection. The report and your account is now limited until 27 Oct 2020, 02:11 UTC. .......
```

То есть конкретно нужно `"27 Oct 2020, 02:11 UTC"`
Как я сделал:

```
$pattern = "/\d{1,2}\s\D{2,4}\s\d{4},\s(\d{2}:\d{2})\sUTC/";
preg_match($pattern, $text, $str);
```

Подскажите, нормальная реализация? Или можно как-то проще это реализовать? То, в регулярках не силен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно короче

```
\d\d?\s\D{2,4}\s\d{4},\s\d{2}:\d{2}\sUTC
```

Но учти, что у тебя подходят и невалидные даты типа 42 октября